# Make a bot send the exact same message but remove the first part of it. (d.py)

Tags: discord.py

I have a discord bot (py) which has a poll command. At the moment the poll command is a simple yes or no as it adds the thumbsup and thumbsdown reactions.

But i would like it so it removes the message and re sends it. But when it is resent it removes the prefix.

The original message should look like this:
**m/poll Do you like gaming?**

I would like the bot to resend it like this:
**do you like gaming?**

then add the reactions. How would i do this. Also this is an`on_message` command as the commands package would not work as well.

Comment: What is some code you have already tried?

Comment: i havent tried anything as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's two ways you can do it :

- With `commands`

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='m/')

@commands.command()
async def poll(ctx, *, question):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    message = await ctx.send(f"New poll: {question}")
    await message.add_reaction('❌')
    await message.add_reaction('✔️')
```

- With a `on_message` event:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
    question = message[7:] #Copy the user message without the 7 first chars (m/poll )
    message = await ctx.send(f"New poll: {question}")
    await message.add_reaction('❌')
    await message.add_reaction('✔️')
```